# Inserting x rows after a date value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert x rows, `x =12` after a cell value, i.e date, and my code does not work, please help,

```
Sub HHRowInserter()
Dim HHRw As Range
For Each HHRw In Range("A1:A2251")
If HHRw.Value Like #9/30/2017# Then   'mm/dd/yyyy '30-Sep-17
HHRw.Offset(12, 0).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next HHRw
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code is inserting a single row at a location 12 rows below HHRw:

```
HHRw.Offset(12, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

To insert 12 rows, you need to declare a 12 row range:

```
Range(HHRw.Offset(1).Address & ":" & HHRw.Offset(12).Address).EntireRow.Insert
```

Keep in mind that your For loop is looping from rows 1 to 2251.  When you locate a date and paste 12 rows, you then push all content below the paste location downward by 12 rows.  By the time you reach the 2251st row, you may have a significant amount of content beyond this row, and this content will not be checked by your For loop.

One way you might go about resolving this is to re-check for the last used row and turn the loop into a Do While:

```
Sub RowInserter()

    Dim LastRow As Integer, LoopCounter As Integer
    Dim TestCell As Range

    LoopCounter = 1
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Do While LoopCounter <= LastRow
        Set TestCell = Range("A" & LoopCounter)
        If IsDate(TestCell.Value) Then
            If DateValue(TestCell.Value) = DateValue("30-Sep-2017") Then
                Range(TestCell.Offset(1).Address & ":" & TestCell.Offset(12).Address).EntireRow.Insert
                LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 13
            Else
                LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1
            End If
        Else
            LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1
        End If
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: nothing happened, when i amended as per your advise

Comment: I have edited the code above, using the IsDate function.

Comment: Fixed and checked on my comp.

Comment: Still not working, i can send you the dummy data if you have email

Comment: Can you just type the first 10 rows or so of values in your original question so we can have record of it here?

Comment: Row1 To Date
Row2 Blank
Row3 Blank
Row4 Blank
Row5 Blank
Row6 Blank
Row7 Blank
Row8 Blank
Row9 Blank
Row10 Blank
Row11 Blank
Row12 Blank
Row13 Blank
Row14 Blank
Row15 Blank
Row16 Blank
Row17 Blank
Row18 Blank
Row19 Date
Row20 x
Row21 x
Row22 x
Row23 x
Row24 x
Row25 x
Row26 x
Row27 x
Row28 x
Row29 x
Row30 x
Row31 30-Sep-17
Row32 Blank
Row33 Blank
Row34 Blank
Row35 Data 
Row36 Data 
Row37 Data 
Row38 Data 
Row39 Date
Row40 x
Row41 x
Row42 x
Row43 x
Row44 x
Row45 x
Row46 x
Row47 x
Row48 x
Row49 x
Row50 x
Row51 30-Sep-17

Comment: That was a bit hard to sift through, but given your data, there should be 12 rows inserted below cells 31 and 51, since those are the only ones which contain date values.  The rest are either non-dates or blank.  I put the values you listed in column A, ran the macro, and it inserted rows as expected.

Comment: x are dates, there is spread of 21 from each sep date to each sep date, the dates start at row 20 and the cycle happens 112 times

Comment: Sep date is the last value

Comment: I just copied "30-Sep-17" to each of the cells with "x", reran the macro, and it worked perfectly.  Is your data in Column A of the active worksheet?  Make sure you re-paste the entire macro as it was edited multiple times.

Comment: x is date value which is not 30 sep 17

Comment: Yes, I know that.  But obviously they should be all formatted the same, right?  For testing purposes, it doesn't make a difference what date they are.  They will all evaluate to true when checked with IsDate().  If they are not being found, then they are not entered in a date format.

Comment: i have closed my spreadsheet and opened a new book, and pasted your code its added 12 rows for every date, i want it only to add 12 rows if its 30 sep 2017

Comment: the reason i need it to add it after 30 sep 2017 as its the last value and i need to insert rows for a table, there will be 112, 30 sep 2017, so hence 112 times 12 rows will be inserted

Comment: I'm sorry that I misunderstood your question as it appeared to me you wanted to add rows after any date.  I have edited the code to check that the DateValue matches 30-Sep-2017.

Comment: Works for me.  You may have tried to use some code that I was in the middle of editing.

Comment: its inserting 31 rows after 30 sep, i only want 12, but thank you for being determined to get this correct

Comment: Of course it can, it's just code.  It can be tweeked however you want.  I am not sure what's causing it to insert 31 rows.  It inserts 12 for me.

Comment: it does the job, is there away defining a name range for example which is 12 row table and inserting that instead of the 12 rows?

Comment: Hi DGulledge, is there a way I can in cooperate this bit of code, so that it copies 12 rows of data from a defined range and sheet into your code,

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow